# Perforce how to create a branch spec with multiple source to a single destination

Tags: perforce, p4v

According to the API guideline
https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v15.1/dvcs/_specify_mappings.html

It seems that I can only specify a one-to-one mapping. Is there any way I can specify a mapping with two sources into one destination?

For example:

```
//stream/main/... //depot/main/...
//stream/build/... //depot/main/...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branch mappings are one-to-one.  If you want to integrate multiple sources into one target, you need multiple branch mappings and multiple integrate commands.  (I would recommend multiple submits as well; it is technically possible to squash multiple integrations into one submit but it multiplies the complexity of the conflict resolution process.)

Comment: Thanks, it's much harder than I thought

Comment: Does `//stream/build` not get merged into `//stream/main`?  If it does, there's no reason you'd need to merge the two into `//depot/main` separately.  (If it doesn't, why doesn't it?  As a general rule everything is supposed to get merged back to the mainline.)

Answer (score 1):

YMMV, but pretty sure that after 2004.1, you should be able to use the + syntax to append rules instead of overwriting, like:

```
//stream/main/... //depot/main/...
+//stream/build/... //depot/main/...
```

Here is the associated [reference on perforce views](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/views.html)